# Meteor client side methods

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor.method defined on the server side (in .js in /server) and I can call it just fine (with callback) from a client-side template script.
I want to do a similar thing but would like it all to be client side so I moved the method to a client script but the result comes back as 'undefined'.

```
Template.showDialog.events({
    'click #clickme' : function() {
        Meteor.call('foo', 'ola', function(error, result) {
            alert('here');
            alert(result);
            });
        }
});

Meteor.methods({
    foo: function (myarg) {
        return myarg+'CLI';
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, both very useful but I gave the answer to the one that was easiest to understand. I actually didn't realise that I could use plain old javascript and thought I was limited to 'Meteor.call' for function calls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com#meteor_methods), where it is explained that methods on the client are stubs, not actual methods:

> If you do define a stub, when a client invokes a server method it will also run its stub in parallel. **On the client, the return value of a stub is ignored**. Stubs are run for their side-effects: they are intended to simulate the result of what the server's method will do, but without waiting for the round trip delay. If a stub throws an exception it will be logged to the console.

Since the result is ignored, you're seeing `undefined`. Don't use methods on the client for this purpose. Just use a javascript function.

Comment: I had read the docs and saw the bit about stubs bit I did not understand it. You have described it in a way that I now see what is happening - thanks.

Comment: Yes, use a pure Javascript function in your React component or Blaze template

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> Calling `methods` on the client defines stub functions associated with server methods of the same name.

Basically, you need to define the method on the server side.  It's also not clear why you'd want to define a method on the client and then call it on the client as well.  Would a vanilla javascript function not do the job perfectly well?

Apologies if I've misunderstood what you're trying to achieve here.